# Agregar elementos a la lista del modelo en la vista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

Estoy usando  Asp.Net Core Mvc 2.0. Tengo una vista que recibe un modelo, dentro del modelo tengo una lista.
Quiero agregar elementos en esa lista desde la vista sin ir al controlador.
La idea seria usando Razor al tocar el boton "agregarDireccion" tomar los elementos del input crear una direccion y guardarla en el modelo de la vista. Luego al tocar guardar ir al controlador y persistir la lista.

Vista:

```
@model AgregarDireccionViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<hr />
<form id="form" asp-action="Edit form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="example-basic">
            <h3>Direccion</h3>
          <input id="calle" type="text" value="Calle" />
          <input id="numero" type="text" value="Numero" />
          <button id="agregarDireccion" value="Agregar direccion"> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />      
</form>
```

Modelo:

```
  public class AgregarDireccionViewModel
        {
            public List<Direccion> direcciones = new List<Direccion>();
        }
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta, e Indica por favor el Modelo la Vista y el Controlador para poder responderte. También explica algo mejor (con un ejemplo) que es realmente lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: No es posible, porque no puedes cambiar datos del servidor en el back-end desde una vista en el front-end sin pasar nueva vez por el back-end.

Comment: Puedes leer el siguiente articulo agregas elementos a una tabla y los eliminas todo del lado del usuario solo es cuestion que lo adaptes para cuando quieras guardar envies la info al servidor.https://www.codemag.com/Article/1511031/CRUD-in-HTML-JavaScript-and-jQuery